# jquery map an object with key and value

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I am trying to map a json object to an array with values associated to the keys. I need to keep keys and values associated because I will do a sort on the created array after.
My object look like this :

```
{"178":"05HY24","179":"1HY12","292":"1HY24","180":"3HY12"}
```

I have tryed to do the array with this function :

```
value=$.map(value, function(value, key) { return key,value; });
```

But keys are not associated to my values. Keys are 0,1,2,3 and not 178,179,292,180.
I try a lot of things but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Because `array` index starts from **Zero**

Comment: Are you basically after an array of objects? e.g. [{178: "05HY24"}, {179:"1H&12"}, etc. ] ?

Comment: My data are not in an array. I only have one object with keys assiciated to values

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kaxdk5v8/1/ ?

Comment: ok, but how can I sort my new array on values after? I can't use the sort function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var myHashMap = JSON.parse('{"178":"05HY24","179":"1HY12","292":"1HY24","180":"3HY12"}');
console.log(myHashMap[178]);
// => "05HY24"

// now map to array..
var myArray = $.map(myHashMap, function(value, index) {
   return [value];
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: it still give me an object. I want an array to do array operation after

Comment: at the end if I do a console.log(myArray[292]) the result is undefined and not 1HY24. The keys are lost

Comment: @Etienne that's because it is an array, not an object - like you wanted. Edit: I'm not sure you quite know what you actually want/need - but take a look at this answer if you want to sort objects: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16794116/1173155

Comment: ok so I can't have keys associated to values in a javascript array. I can only have key begining to 0.

Comment: if you use myHashMap after the JSON.parse() you should have an object with keys.
So you can do myHashMap.292 and it'll return 1HY24

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using jQuery:

```js
var values = {
  "178": "05HY24",
  "179": "1HY12",
  "292": "1HY24",
  "180": "3HY12"
};
var array = [];
for (var k in values)
  array.push({
    'k': k,
    'v': values[k]
  });
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.k - b.k;
});
console.log(array);
```